# polkadot query api and None parameter

Tags: polkadot-js, api, javascript

Some API queries accept optional parameters Option that can be omitted.

How are those queries written with the javascript API?

For example:

`api.query.preimage.preimageFor()` takes an `Option<(H256,u32)>` and returns the preimage of given hash and legth.

However this option can be set to None (in the Dev console for example) then it returns a list of preimages, how is that query written in javascript?

`pi = await api.query.preimage.preimageFor(None)`, what is `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.entries()` to retrieve all the info, check the docs https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/storage/#how-do-i-use-entrieskeys-on-double-maps

In your case you can use something like could work

```js
const allEntries = await api.query.preimage.preimageFor.entries();
allEntries.forEach(([{ args: [[hash,len]] }, value]) => {
  console.log(`hash: ${hash}, len: ${len}, value: ${value.toHuman()}`);
});
```

Thx!

Comment: thanks! I would have not guessed this. I did not associate preimageFor with being a map-type storage entry... thanks!